# Rails, how do I chain scopes with an “OR” operator between them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, orm, chain, scopes

This is a question that spun out of "[Rails, how do I chain scopes with an "and" operator between them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26483569/rails-how-do-i-chain-scopes-with-an-and-operator-between-them/26484560?noredirect=1#comment41612186_26484560)".

In the accepted answer, the code example generates SQL looking something like:

```
"where 'age' similar to '%(foo|bar)%' AND 'name' similar to '%(foo|bar)%' AND
```

... and so on.

How would I implement this if I want to chain the scopes with `OR` instead of `AND`?

Comment: Duplicate:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639656/activerecord-or-query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[check the `any_of` gem.](https://github.com/oelmekki/activerecord_any_of)

Lets you do things like:

```
banned_users      = User.where(banned: true)
unconfirmed_users = User.where("confirmed_at IS NULL")
inactive_users    = User.where.any_of(banned_users, unconfirmed_users)
```